# ArangoDB sharding cluster performance issue

Tags: arangodb

I have a query that runs well in single-instance setup. However, when I tried to run it on a sharded cluster, the performance dropped (4x longer execution time).

The query plan shows that practically all processing is done on Coordinator node, not on DbServer.
**How to push the query to be executed at DbServer?**

To give a bit of a context: I have a collection of ~120k (will grow to several millions) of multi-level JSON documents with nested arrays. And the query needs to unnest these arrays before getting to the proper node.

**AQL Query:**

```
for doc IN doccollection
for arrayLevel1Elem in doc.report.container.children.container
for arrayLevel2Elem in arrayLevel1Elem.children.container.children.num
for arrayLevel3Elem in arrayLevel2Elem.children.code

filter doc.report.container.concept.simpleCodedValue == 'A' 
filter arrayLevel1Elem.concept.codedValue == "B"
filter arrayLevel2Elem.concept.simpleCodedValue == "C"   
filter arrayLevel3Elem.concept.simpleCodedValue == 'X'
filter arrayLevel3Elem.value.simpleCodedValue == 'Y'     

collect studyUid = doc.report.study.uid, personId = doc.report.person.id, metricName = arrayLevel2Elem.concept.meaning, value = to_number(arrayLevel2Elem.value)

return {studyUid, personId, metricName, value}
```

**Query Plan:**

```
 Id   NodeType                  Site          Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode             DBS              1   * ROOT
  2   EnumerateCollectionNode   DBS         121027     - FOR doc IN doccollection   /* full collection scan, projections: `report`, 2 shard(s) */   FILTER (doc.`report`.`container`.`concept`.`simpleCodedValue` == "A")   /* early pruning */
  3   CalculationNode           DBS         121027       - LET #8 = doc.`report`.`container`.`children`.`container`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: doc : doccollection */
 19   CalculationNode           DBS         121027       - LET #24 = doc.`report`.`study`.`uid`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: doc : doccollection */
 20   CalculationNode           DBS         121027       - LET #26 = doc.`report`.`person`.`id`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: doc : doccollection  */
 29   RemoteNode                COOR        121027       - REMOTE
 30   GatherNode                COOR        121027       - GATHER   /* parallel, unsorted */
  4   EnumerateListNode         COOR      12102700       - FOR arrayLevel1Elem IN #8   /* list iteration */
 11   CalculationNode           COOR      12102700         - LET #16 = (arrayLevel1Elem.`concept`.`codedValue` == "B")   /* simple expression */
 12   FilterNode                COOR      12102700         - FILTER #16
  5   CalculationNode           COOR      12102700         - LET #10 = arrayLevel1Elem.`children`.`container`.`children`.`num`   /* attribute expression */
  6   EnumerateListNode         COOR    1210270000         - FOR arrayLevel2Elem IN #10   /* list iteration */
 13   CalculationNode           COOR    1210270000           - LET #18 = (arrayLevel2Elem.`concept`.`simpleCodedValue` == "C")   /* simple expression */
 14   FilterNode                COOR    1210270000           - FILTER #18
  7   CalculationNode           COOR    1210270000           - LET #12 = arrayLevel2Elem.`children`.`code`   /* attribute expression */
 21   CalculationNode           COOR    1210270000           - LET #28 = arrayLevel2Elem.`concept`.`meaning`   /* attribute expression */
 22   CalculationNode           COOR    1210270000           - LET #30 = TO_NUMBER(arrayLevel2Elem.`value`)   /* simple expression */
  8   EnumerateListNode         COOR  121027000000           - FOR arrayLevel3Elem IN #12   /* list iteration */
 15   CalculationNode           COOR  121027000000             - LET #20 = ((arrayLevel3Elem.`concept`.`simpleCodedValue` == "X") && (arrayLevel3Elem.`value`.`simpleCodedValue` == "Y"))   /* simple expression */
 16   FilterNode                COOR  121027000000             - FILTER #20
 23   CollectNode               COOR   96821600000             - COLLECT studyUid = #24, personId = #26, metricName = #28, value = #30   /* hash */
 26   SortNode                  COOR   96821600000             - SORT studyUid ASC, personId ASC, metricName ASC, value ASC   /* sorting strategy: standard */
 24   CalculationNode           COOR   96821600000             - LET #32 = { "studyUid" : studyUid, "personId" : personId, "metricName" : metricName, "value" : value }   /* simple expression */
 25   ReturnNode                COOR   96821600000             - RETURN #32
```

Thanks a lot for any hint.

Answer (score 2):

Queries are not actually executed at the DB server - the coordinators handle query compilation and execution, only really asking the DB server(s) for data.

This means memory load for query execution happens on the coordinators (good!) but that the coordinator has to transport (sometimes LARGE amounts of) data across the network.  This is THE BIGGEST downside to moving to a cluster - and not one that is easily solved.

I walked this same road in the beginning and found ways to optimize ***some*** of my queries, but in the end, it was easier to go with a "[one-shard](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.7/release-notes-new-features36.html#oneshard)" cluster or an "[active-failover](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.7/architecture-deployment-modes-active-failover.html)" setup.

It's tricky to make architecture suggestions because each use case can be so different, but there are some general AQL guidelines I follow:

1. Collecting `FOR` and `FILTER` statements is not recommended (see #2).  Try this version to see if it runs any faster (and try indexing `report.container.concept.simpleCodedValue`) :

```
FOR doc IN doccollection
    FILTER doc.report.container.concept.simpleCodedValue == 'A'
    FOR arrayLevel1Elem in doc.report.container.children.container
        FILTER arrayLevel1Elem.concept.codedValue == 'B'
        FOR arrayLevel2Elem in arrayLevel1Elem.children.container.children.num
            FILTER arrayLevel2Elem.concept.simpleCodedValue == 'C'
            FOR arrayLevel3Elem in arrayLevel2Elem.children.code
                FILTER arrayLevel3Elem.concept.simpleCodedValue == 'X'
                FILTER arrayLevel3Elem.value.simpleCodedValue == 'Y'
                COLLECT
                    studyUid = doc.report.study.uid,
                    personId = doc.report.person.id,
                    metricName = arrayLevel2Elem.concept.meaning,
                    value = to_number(arrayLevel2Elem.value)
                RETURN { studyUid, personId, metricName, value }
```

2. The `FOR doc IN doccollection` pattern will recall the ENTIRE document from the DB server for each item in `doccollection`.  Best practice is to either limit the number of documents you are retrieving (best done with an index-backed search) and/or return only a few attributes.  Don't be afraid of using `LET` - in-memory on the coordinator can be faster than in-memory on the DB.  This example does both - filters *and* returns a smaller set of data:

```
LET filteredDocs = (
    FOR doc IN doccollection
        FILTER doc.report.container.concept.simpleCodedValue == 'A'
        RETURN {
            study_id: doc.report.study.uid,
            person_id: doc.report.person.id,
            arrayLevel1: doc.report.container.children.container
        }
)
FOR doc IN filteredDocs
    FOR arrayLevel1Elem in doc.arrayLevel1
        FILTER arrayLevel1Elem.concept.codedValue == 'B'
        ...
```

Comment: Hi Kerry, 

Thanks a lot for your swift yet elaborate recommendation. 

I followed your guidelines and managed to improve performance:
  1. The biggest impact (20%: ~100s -> ~80s) has come from adding an index on the first filtered field (report.container.concept.simpleCodedValue). I skipped it initially as it has low cardinality and in case of single-instance architecture it didn't impact the performance.
  2. Moving filter statements up has not changed the performance. In the execution plan posted above you can see that optimizer already applied move-filters-up rule.

Comment: cont'd   
   
  3. Using LET statement helped again a bit (~80s -> ~75s)
But still, it doesn't look great when compared to 20s execution time on single instance.

So, I need to agree with you sharding cluster is not the best option in my case of mass data extraction. At least as long as query cannot be fully processed on DbServer node. 
In fact, ArangoDB "One Shard" feature sents the query to DbServer. But then we loose horizontal scalability what I expected to achieve.

Anyways, thanks again for your experience-based feedback - helped a lot with understanding the logic behind.

Comment: @kgr - that's sometimes the way it goes.  You can only do so much with certain queries, and a cluster is not always the best way to go.  I was also hoping for horizontal scalability but found that my queries were not well-suited.  That said, there are ways to make it run more efficiently.

Comment: @kgr - the key is making sure you understand the underlying architecture and where the bottlenecks are.  For instance, the trouble you're having seems to be with a big query on a cluster - lots of data moving between the DB and Coord nodes.  To minimize this, try creating a Foxx service that makes lots of smaller queries, doing some of the joins or filtering in JavaScript, minimizing the amount of data from the DB or number of messages between DB nodes.  Also, this is what "SmartGraph" is designed to help with.  

https://www.arangodb.com/enterprise-server/smartgraphs/

Comment: You might be right with SmartGraph feature. In my case I even have Disjoint SmartGraphs. And, according to the documentation, "This ensures that graph traversals, shortest path, and k-shortest-paths queries can be executed locally on a DB-Server". Definitely worth checking out. Thanks again.